# Dot-operator in haskell

Tags: haskell, operators, dot-operator

I have a function, that uses the Dot-operator. Now I want to write it without the dot. How can I do this?

```
all p = and . map p
```

Is this right?

```
all p = and (map p)
```

I get these errors:

```
4.hs:8:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Bool]'
                with actual type `[a0] -> [b0]'
    In the return type of a call of `map'
    Probable cause: `map' is applied to too few arguments
    In the first argument of `and', namely `(map p)'
    In the expression: and (map p)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at the [definition](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) of `(.)`:

```
f . g  =  \ x -> f (g x)
```

Expanding this gives

```
and . (map p)  =  \x -> and ((map p) x)
```

or

```
all p x  =  and (map p x)
```

Answer (score 4):

Removing `(.)` requires adding explicitly the argument that the dot is "threading" through your functions.  You want something like

```
all p xs = and (map p xs)
```